# Windows builds of an Electron app on Cent OS 64 bit with electron-packager fails with error

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to set up build on a remote Cent OS server and stuck with error. I installed wine, but since the server has 64-bit architecture, wine command is `wine64`, not just `wine`. Each time I try to make a Windows build, I get the `Could not find "wine" on your system... Make sure that the "wine" executable is in your PATH.` error. It seems like it's trying to execute "wine" command, but I have "wine64" instead, and according to various guides, it's ok. Making an alias didn't help. 
Could someone suggest how I can workaround this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: have you been able to create an electron-package running on your server?

Comment: for Linux - yes, it does not require wine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, I built only 64-bit version, but I had to build and install 32-bit version as well. Even though compilation and installation went with warning that some 32-bit stuff is missing, the electron builds seem to be OK and work OK.

The tutorial I finally followed [is here](http://www.systutorials.com/239913/install-32-bit-wine-1-8-centos-7/).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error:

```
Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v4.2.12
Could not find "wine64" on your system.

Wine is required to use the appCopyright, appVersion, buildVersion, icon, and 
win32metadata parameters for Windows targets.

Make sure that the "wine64" executable is in your PATH.

See https://github.com/electron/electron-packager#building-windows-apps-from-non-windows-platforms for details.
```

Running these steps in terminal, allowed me to resolve this issue:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew doctor
brew cask install wine-stable
```

Source: https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/

Comment: this is for mac

Comment: last command can be something like: brew install --cask --no-quarantine wine-stable